# collection-repeat overlap cards while ng-repeat works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

`Ng-Repeat` works fine. Each cards is separated from each other. No overlapping

[image]

Now . `Collection_repeat` , this will overlap all cards.

[image]

```
<ion-view view-title="Header"> <ion-content>
<div class="im-wrapper">
    <div collection-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img ng-src='{{item.authorUrl}}'>
            <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.date}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
            <img class="full-image" ng-src='{{item.imageUrl}}'>
            <p>{{item.content}}</p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="subdued">{{item.likes}} Like</a> <a href="#"
                    class="subdued">{{item.comments}} Comments</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>


</ion-content> </ion-view>
```

This text is added to increase the text content in question, as the page is giving error while submitting. Please ignore this text.

Comment: Create a fiddle/plunkr?

Comment: maybe try setting item-width and item-height explicitly then see if that help.